# How to sort dictionary with multiple items

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I found some similar questions about this, but suggested codes doesn´t work for my dictionary where I use tuple and I´m not good enough to edit them for my needs, it still gives me the errors. But I guess I need to use the lambda function somehow.

To clarify more the situation: I write a script for ANSA software, which selects separate PID regions of the model (each region consist of a number of elements) and then creates a connections between them. To decide which region should be connected with which I need to mark the regions with some numbers. The regions should be marked from 0 to some final number depending on their coordinates. So I think easiest way is to just sort the created dictionary as mentioned above. Then I would know if I select third item in dictionary, it would be third region of elements from the left side of the model.

The dictionary contains this:

```
{

(<Entity: 0x00007FF4261EE661: type: 513(513,N_CQUAD4) id:-354900>, <Entity: 0x00007FF4264AE648: type: 513(513,N_CQUAD4) id:-354901>, <Entity: 0x00007FF4264AD0A0: type: 513(513,N_CQUAD4) id:-355476>): [32.50000221162431, 73.00083277940169, 171.00023861627614], 

(<Entity: 0x00007FF4261EE662: type: 513(513,N_CQUAD4) id:-354901>, <Entity: 0x00007FF4264AE648: type: 513(513,N_CQUAD4) id:-354901>, <Entity: 0x00007FF4264AD0A0: type: 513(513,N_CQUAD4) id:-355476>): [51.50000221162431, 44.00083277940169, 125.00023861627614],

(<Entity: 0x00007FF4261EE660: type: 513(513,N_CQUAD4) id:-354902>, <Entity: 0x00007FF4264AE648: type: 513(513,N_CQUAD4) id:-354901>, <Entity: 0x00007FF4264AD0A0: type: 513(513,N_CQUAD4) id:-355476>): [11.50000221162431, 23.00083277940169, 106.00023861627614]

}
```

In the first, longer part of each item (the round brackets) is the list of elements with their properties. "Entity is some unique number, I actually have no idea for what it is used. "Type" says what shape element has, and "id" is obviously id of the element. I don´t know what more I could say about them.

The values in squared brackets at the end of each item are x,y,z coordinates.
What I need is to sort the items of the dictionary according to the coordinates (not the order of coordinates!). First x, then z and then y. Could anyone help me with this?

I tried for example this, but I´m afraid it needs to be much more complicated than this:

```
region_position = sorted(region_position, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[3], x[2]))
```

Comment: That is not a valid dictionary. What does the dictionary actually look like?

Comment: dict in python is an unordered collection by definition (so there's no index), therefore you can't sort a dictionary. You may find useful the OrderedDict (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: @EduGord dicts maintain the insertion order since Python 3.7  so in theory `dict(sorted(dict.items(), key=...))` would work, but you are correct in that there is no sense of indexing into a dict

Comment: I think this application for ansa. yes you can do this. but not straight forward. have to do some workaround. shall I simplify this dictionary for better understanding?

Comment: *"they are not important for this question"* Yes, they are. You are literally asking a question about them. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @Olvin Roght This is what print() gives me. I only selected 3 items from it because otherwise it would be impossibly long. And I put each item on a new line here, so it would be easier to orient in it for you. Otherwise it would be a one long line.

Comment: @Viswa Yes, it is for ANSA. I didn´t think someone familiar with this software would see this question:) I´m pretty new to Python, but nevertheless I was tasked by my employee to do some script which I think is complicated as hell. So I constantly ask BETA support for help with their python commands and I was given a piece of code for selection of separate PID regions of elements, which stores the selected PID regions into this dictionary with tuples, which I don´t completely understand, even though I did some research.

Comment: @DeepSpace My question is just about how to sort a dictionary if It has this structure. I don´t want to sort it by values of that elements. Just by the coordinates in the second part of the item. In "elements" part of item there could be list of anything else I guess.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say the simplest way would be to create a new dictionary with the same keys and the proper ordering of x,z,y inside.

A one-liner would be (with `oldDict` the previous dictionary):

`newDict = {k:[oldDict[k][0], oldDict[k][2], oldDict[k][1]] for k in oldDict}`

Here, I am building a dictionary the same way I would a list-comprehension, iterating through each "k" key of the old dictionary, and assigning to each key a new list with the element in the order I want (here 0, 2 and 1, to re-order x, z and y).

Comment: I´m not sure if I get it correctly, but I don´t want to change the order of x, y, z. I want to sort the whole items according to these values. If you look at the example above, there are three items and I need to change the order of these according to x, y, z values. If the items would contain for example something like this - {(blabla):[10, 20, 30], (blabla):[50, 20, 10], (blabla):[10, 40, 5]}, the items should be ordered like this: {(blabla):[10, 40, 5], (blabla):[10, 20, 30], (blabla):[50, 20, 10]}. First by x, then z and then y in increasing order.

Comment: It seems you are misunderstanding how dictionaries work. There is no numerical indexing, you access each item by its key ("blabla" in your example), independently from the order they are printed when you do a "print()".

Comment: Yes, I´m "a little" confused about it, not to mention tuples. I´m really bad in this, yet I´m forced to work with it :( So the way would be to convert the dictionary to some list?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the thing you are working on, but I think you should be using a dataframe (from the pandas library) for this kind of thing. It will require some work from you to get used to this kind of object though. Think of it as a table (like an Excel table), but in Python.